# Failing to Extract Hexadecimal Value from TextBox and Store It In A Integer Variable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox

I have a textbox

```
<TextBox Height="23" Grid.Column="1" PreviewTextInput="AddressBox_PreviewTextInput" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,27,13,0" Name="AddressI2C" Text="{Binding Path=AddressMessage, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" />

    private string _AddressMessage = string.Empty;
    public string AddressMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _AddressMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            _AddressMessage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AddressMessage");
        }
    }
```

Now In my view Model class I have a method which requires me to get the text stored in this textbox and save it in a int variable. Now here is the trick, I have to save only the **hexadecimal** values inside this variable.

**Demonstration:**

Textbox value: 0x18

So I should first of all take the text inside the textbox and store only the hexadecimal value inside the variable int. Basically store only 18 inside the integer variable.

I had done this in my C++ aplication as follows:

```
int address = m_texteditAddress->getText().getHexValue32();
```

I tried doing the following:

```
string strValue = AddressMessage;
if(strValue.StartsWith("0x"))
{
    strValue = strValue.Remove(0,2);
    int address = Convert.ToInt32(strValue);         
}
```

but AddressMessage is always empty even though I am entering "0x23" when I debug the code. The control doesnt enter the loop. Now how can I achieve this????

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int address = int.Parse(MyTextBox.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: Please do not just post code as an answer, add a sentences or two explaining why this code should work.

Comment: Well i tried this. It doesnt work. MyTextBox.text doesnot seem to work. I have updated the question

Comment: @Sam, for a C# programmer, this C# code is pretty much self explanatory. I rather appreciate to the point answers. There is no *rocket-science* in this code.

Comment: @vulcanraven Code-only answer are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/188646). While this answer is quite basic, so is the question and the OP is obviously struggling with the concept. Understand that rocket science is not mind boggling for rocket scientists, a sentence or two won't kill you, it may even explain why "`MyTextBox.text` doesnot seem to work".

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is bound to the `AddressMessage` property, just grab that value. Also, your example just stripped off the "0x" from the hex string, so just use `String.SubString()`.

Example:

```
int address = int.Parse(AddressMessage.Substring(2));
```

If you need to actually convert the hex string to the actual integer it represents use `System.Convert`:

```
int address = Convert.ToInt32(AddressMessage, 16);
```

Comment: Hey @Bryan thanks for the reply :) I tried using it, it throws the following error when I debug it: "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex"

Comment: I actually need to take 0x12 from textbox and store oly 12 into the address variable. I tried the way you have mentioned above but it throws error as mentioned above

Comment: Was the value of the textbox indeed "0x12"? Sounds like your property isn't bound correctly and instead AddressMessage is an empty string.

Comment: Make sure you are setting the data context correctly for your view.